# Cosmos DB - ORDER BY clause only returns 1 document

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have about 500 documents with the same value for the partitionkey (/userprofileId) in one container and as soon as I add an ORDER BY clause to the SQL the results are incorrect.

`SELECT * FROM c where c.userprofileId='LogSmsOutbound'` returns all documents

`SELECT * FROM c where c.userprofileId='LogSmsOutbound' ORDER BY c.MessageDTCreated` returns only 1 document

`SELECT * FROM c where c.userprofileId='LogSmsOutbound' ORDER BY c.MessageDTCreated OFFSET 0 LIMIT 5` returns ZERO documents

In summary it seems that the indexing policy needs to be changed, but before I do that I would need to know the justification, so could anyone provide information please?

It would seem strange that I need to change the indexing policy since I'm using the default one at the time of creating the container:

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ]
}
```

Sample document

```
    {
        "type": "LogSmsOutbound",
        "id": "SMce682b0a9d0f404682d59230d573fd5a23",
        "userprofileId": "LogSmsOutbound",
        "dtupdated": "2020-06-01T17:05:02.267599+00:00",
        "fromNr": "+XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "status": "delivered",
        "toNr": "+YYYYYYYYYYY",
        "userIds": [
            "5FB72F43243245D5F14B0634232432A63EBA9C217E3299"
        ],
        "ttl": 2592000,
        "MessageDTCreated": "2020-06-01T17:02:51+00:00",
        "MessageDTSent": "2020-06-01T17:02:51+00:00",
    }
```

I'm speculating that the indexing policy is incorrect and that the following section needs to be removed:

```
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
```

Comment: Just curious: are you specifying a partition key somewhere, for your query?

Comment: Yep, the 'c.userprofileId='LogSmsOutbound' part of the SQL is the partition key

Answer (score 0):

Your container needs to have a composite index defined for this type of query to work properly. You can see an example index policy for defining a composite index in [Composite indexing policy examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-indexing-policy?tabs=dotnetv2%2Cpythonv3#composite-indexing-policy-examples).

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark. However, according to the link you provided it states:  
**If you would like to perform a query that has an ORDER BY clause for multiple properties, a composite index on those properties is required**
Which is not the case for my SQL statements. Looks like I need to report this as a defect with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this the Azure support team found out that the collection was on an old index layout so they migrated the collection to the new indexing layout. As a side note I had other collections with the same data set where these queries were working just fine, so the issue were specific to this collection.

So in the end of the day there wasn't anything wrong with indexing policy.

Considering that the Request Units for below query was only 3.27 I see no reason to experimenting with a composite index:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.userprofileId='LogSmsOutbound' ORDER BY c.MessageDTCreated DESC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 5
```